# VNC ports on virtual machines

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, remote-access

On Ubuntu 12.04 I use VNC to connect to KVM guests.

How can I change the port those use? By default they use port 5900 and increment to 5901 and so on.

Comment: you want it to start from other port automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using libvirt, you can manuall set the ports in virt-manager or in the domxml, (through `virsh edit VMNAME`)

The format is  `<graphics type='vnc' port='PORTNUMBER'/>`

Answer (score 0):

Specify the port when you start the KVM image, e.g.:

```
/path/to/qemu-kvm [...] -vnc :5
```

The port is 5900 + the argument to `-vnc`, in this case, 5905.